# How do I get max string (highest alphabetical string) in Quicksight and display only that?

Tags: string, visualization, amazon-quicksight

For Eg:
We have 30 hobbies of the same member, but we would only want to display the one with the highest alphabetical order. How do we achieve this in Quicksight?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dataset with the following structure

| memberId | hobby |
| --- | --- |
| member1 | reading |
| member1 | swimming |
| member2 | running |

and you want to get this output:

| memberId | hobby |
| --- | --- |
| member1 | swimming |
| member2 | running |

You can achieve this by adding a calculated field called `memberRank` as follows:

```
denseRank([hobby DESC], [memberId], PRE_AGG)
```

This field will contain a number indicating the sort order of the hobbies - having value 1 for the hobby with the highest sort order.

Then add a table and add both `memberId` and `hobby` to the group by field well.

Finally add a filter on the `memberRank` field with value equals to 1 so that the table only shows the hobby with the highest sort order for each member.